# Why I´m getting this error : StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[VideosService -> Http

Tags: angular

I am getting this error:

```
core.js:1449 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[VideosService -> Ht**strong text**tp]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[VideosService -> Http]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Http!
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[VideosService -> Http]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[VideosService -> Http]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Http!
```

Comment: Please include the code that causes this error as a minimal example to help understanding what could be the cause.

Comment: You probably missing `@Injectable()` or missing from `providers: []`

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to [import `HttpModule` in `app.module.ts`](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/angular-2-introduction-to-new-http-module-1278499db2a0)

```
// main.ts
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, HttpModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
class AppModule { }

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Comment: you are great now it is working perfectly thank you so much dear

Comment: Haha no worries :) would you mind marking the question correcy @jazz?